# How password hash and salt stored in Symfony database?

Tags: database, symfony, hash, passwords, salt

I am migrating a project from Symfony to Django. I need to import all users with passwords.

To do this I need to know how passwords are stored in the database. For each user password I need to know 4 things:

- the algorithm was used to generate hash
- number of iterations
- the salt was used to generate hash
- resulted hash

The project built on Symfony 3.4. The developers said to me that they are used default hashing algorithm and it is SHA512

I suppose the number of iterations is 1.

Left to find a salt and result hash. Both should be stored in the database.

In the password field in the database stored strings like this:
`fOEJQT89OWYfI+hBHT28RpTQRiWnyo49Rtxqv6DWY/EJ6cSkFdZ0Y36VaqjWI+1NNhRGCHBBGJvwdMD1c7GZfw==`

I expect to find a hash and a salt here
BUT
here are 88 symbols.
SHA512 has a 64 bytes long hash.

What is the format of data stored in this field?
Is both a hash and a salt stored here?

Comment: Hi, check out the `security.yml` file first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the `app/config/security.yml` for the encoders being used. Assuming you have something like the following:

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User: 'sha512'
```

It will use the SHA512 encoder with default settings. From looking at the corresponding Encoder [`MessageDigestPasswordEncoder`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.php#L32) we can gather that it will use 5000 iterations by default and then base64 encode it.

The only thing left is figuring out if a salt was used, and if so how it was generated. Since SHA512 does not generate it's own salt you have to look at the user class and check its `User::getSalt` method. If this returns null, then no salt was used otherwise you will have to mimic its behaviour or retrieve the result when generating the password.